# Operator and canonical transformation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, unitarity

Given the operator,

$$V(b)= \exp{\left[b \left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\right)^2\right]}$$

In the case that $V$ is unitary what canonical transformation does it generate for a free particle of mass $m$?

Comment: How would you propose to arrange unitarity of V?

Comment: So is b an imaginary number, or what case do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator you are writing down is the formal kernel of the celebrated [Weierstrass transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_transform), i.e. convolution by a Gaussian, essentially a low-pass filter, which smooths out high frequency fluctuations.

In quantum mechanics, any invertible operator such as *V* generates a canonical transformation, automatically, 
$$
\hat{x} \mapsto V  \hat{x}  V^{-1} ; \qquad \hat{p} \mapsto V  \hat{p}  V^{-1},
$$
in the sense that it trivially and manifestly preserves the standard commutation relation 
$$
[ \hat{x},\hat{p} ]= i\hbar
$$
as an obvious equivalence relation.

However, in this case, as already remarked by LBC, your *V* is 
$V=\exp(-b\hat{p}^2/\hbar^2)$, so that, evidently  $\hat{x} \mapsto   \hat{x} +2ib\hat{p}/\hbar$ and $\hat{p}\mapsto\hat{p}$, canonical alright. Unless *b* is pure imaginary, the transformation mixes hermitian with nonhermitean operators--I presume this underlies your requirement of unitarity, i.e., imaginary *b*.

For imaginary *b*, however, the smoothing effect of the kernel is gone. In phase-space quantization, the kernel provides the bridge between the normal-ordering and the Moyal frames. You might flesh out your question to parse out the *point* of it.

Answer (score 1):

This operator does not appear to be unitary. For $p~=~-i\hbar\partial/\partial x$ this operator is
$$
V(b)~=~\exp\left(-b{\hat p}^2/\hbar^2\right).
$$
For this to be unitary you need $b^*~=~-b$. The conjugate is then $V^\dagger(b)~=~V(b)$, or for $b^*~=~-b$ the you have $V^\dagger(b)~=~V^{-1}(b)$. For unitarity you need $V(b)~=~\exp\left(-ib{\hat p}^2/\hbar^2\right)$. The variable or c-number $b$ then plays the role of time, and this operator is then a time development operator for a free particle with $b~=~it/2m$.

Consider a wave function $\psi(x,t)~=~\exp(-(x~-~x_0)^2/2\sigma)e^{ikx~-~\omega t}$ and we have for simplicity $b$ small so $b^2~\simeq~0$ then
$$
V(b)~\simeq~\left(1~+~b\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^2\right)\exp(-(x~-~x_0)^2/2\sigma)e^{ikx~-~\omega t},
$$
and then
$$
V(b)\psi(x,t)~=~\psi(x,t)\left[1~+~b\left(\frac{x~-~x_0}{\sigma}~+~ik\right)^2~+~\frac{b}{\sigma}\right].
$$
For $b~=~i\delta t/2m$ this is then the time development of the wave function by a small unit of time $\delta t$.

Comment: How does one see that $b$ must play the role of time?

Comment: That $b = it/2m$ is from dimensional analysis. If this is not unitary it could then be $b = -\beta/2m$ for $\beta = 1/kT$ and this operator is a Boltzmann distribution.